# Specify which version to install with macports

Tags: gdb, installation, macports

I would like to install a specific version of gdb and gcc with macports on mac os x leopard, not the last one, but the 6.8 for gdb. Is it possible?

Comment: Why not just use the Apple gcc and gdb that get installed along with Xcode ?

Comment: I want to use Eclipse CDT, and it can not work with Apple's gdb, that is the reason.

Comment: that seems like an awful lot of hassle when you could just use Xcode ?

Comment: with Xcode you can not use reverse debugging, and external plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post is old.. but specifying a version is possible.  For example I want to install ZeroMQ version 3.2.2 so I use:

```
sudo port install zmq @3.2.2
```

And it always helps to goto the MacPorts website and search to see if they have what you are looking for.

Comment: As Adam mentioned, this doesn't work with the current version of MacPorts (2.2.1).

Comment: @TachyonVortex Adam's answer does not seem to provide a fix.  My answer still works, not sure why your having trouble. Oh, and mine is a one-liner :D

Comment: I have the latest version of MacPorts (currently 2.3.3), and for me, running `sudo port install zmq @3.2.2` causes version 3.2.5 to be installed: `Installing zmq @3.2.5_0` `Activating zmq @3.2.5_0`

Comment: @TachyonVortex That does not mean the command is not working.  There is something the maintainers of the zmq repository did to cause that.  They may have deleted the 3.2.2 or made a forced link to 3.2.5.  Please read the macport man pages for 'install'.  Would also recommend checking the zmq version that did install in lieu of what macports displayed as I have seen this strange error before.  BTW: I use homebrew exclusively now :)

Comment: No, this is not an issue with `zmq`. I've just picked five random ports and tried to install older versions using `sudo port install <PORT> @<VERSION>`, and all five installed the current versions. [Here's the log](http://pastebin.com/bhFt2NJq). If older versions could be installed using this method, there wouldn't need to be an article on the official wiki called ["How to install an older version of a port"](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort), which has been [regularly updated over the last 7 years](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort?action=history).

Comment: @tachyonvortex I didn't say it was an issue with ZMQ, just the repo.

Comment: You could follow the instructions for creating a local Portfile repository https://guide.macports.org/#development.local-repositories. Just copy the original Portfile to your local repository, modify the version and rebuild the portindex. This way you could also freeze a version from being updated by the selfupdate command.

Comment: MacPorts dev here. This doesn't work. The @version syntax can only be used if you already have the port installed, but deactivated, to activate the specific version you have.

Comment: @neverpanic this is old but it def worked for me, and apparently others.  Please feel free to correct my post. And you should post what does work.

Comment: No, this doesn't work. It will always install the latest version, unless you already had the older version you specify installed but deactivated (in which case this is equivalent to `port activate $port @$version`). No need to post what works, because the post below this one already does.

Comment: @neverpanic I will take your word for it.  Referring to the post below, I am pretty shocked that after all these years, instead of it being a simple one-liner, its *that*.

Comment: That's because the problem is not easily solvable in the absence of version information in dependency declarations, which MacPorts does not have. As always, this is open source, so patches to fix it are welcome.

Comment: @neverpanic Thanks for the clarification.  I wish I had more time to help out!

Answer (score 29):

It is possible. It's just convoluted and tedious. It's [listed in the documentation these days](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort).

**Steps**

Go to [macports trac](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/) and find the package you're looking for. [This is the link for subversion](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/devel/subversion/Portfile?rev=106629), which is the package I'll be using in the example.

Click the PortFile
[image: Click the portfile]

Click Revision Log (top right)
[image: Click the revision log]

Pour through the revisions until you find the version you're looking for. Remember the revision number.
[image: Finding the version in the revision log]

In this example I'm looking for version 1.7 of subversion.

With that revision number noted. You need to checkout the version of that subdirectory at that revision.

```
cd /tmp
svn co http://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/trunk/dports/devel/subversion --revision 106629
```

Then cd into the folder and run the install

```
cd subversion
sudo port install
```

Then it should become selected by default. You can check with

```
sudo port installed subversion
The following ports are currently installed:
  subversion @1.7.10_0 (active)
  subversion @1.8.8_0
  subversion @1.8.10_0
```

Comment: It appears I've got a downvote on this answer. Could the downvoter explain? If there's something wrong in the answer it would be useful to know.

Comment: Worked nicely for me, but your mileage might vary.

Comment: Development seems to have moved from trac to github: https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/

Answer (score 5):

As I just came across this question when trying to figure out how to download an older version of curl, I thought I'd share an update:

The currently accepted answer did not work for me any longer. This is with MacPorts 2.2.0. What I did was the following.

I started following the directions located [here](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort). I ended up using the SVN method, since the first method didn't work. What I didn't realize is that I was missing a critical step.

I found another post that suggested moving the downloaded directory to `/private/tmp`. After doing this, I `cd` into the new directory and after a `sudo port install` I was able to install the older version.

I am on a Mac running OS X 10.8, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: That [InstallingOlderPort](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort) wiki article has been recently updated to cover this issue. The downloaded Portfile must be placed in a directory (such as `/tmp`) which MacPorts can read.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know it is not possible at all to install other versions than the exact version, unless there is a specific port for a certain version.

The only thing you could do is fetch the portfile of the desired version from the Macports subversion repository.

In your case only gdb 7.2 is available on the current version, no variants and no other versions - sorry :)